# Both HTTP and HTTPS versions of my site are currently indexed on Google. Is that hurting SEO?

Tags: seo, https, http

When on Google, I search for the name of my site, with no HTTP, HTTPS or WWW and the results that come up are the HTTPS, then another listing for HTTPS page and then the HTTP version.

Is the fact that Google is indexing the HTTP **and** HTTPS version of my site hurting my SEO in any way?

Comment: Short answer? Yes. You should pick one. Since you have gone through the trouble of setting up a certificate, and HTTPS increases trust scores slightly, then I suggest that you redirect your HTTP site to HTTPS to remedy the situation. Make sure your HTTPS site is working properly before doing so. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it’s hurting your SEO

#### You should 301 redirect your HTTP to HTTPS.

[Google has stated](https://security.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal_6.html):

> We’re starting to use HTTPS as a ranking signal. For now it's only a very lightweight signal...But over time, we may decide to strengthen it, because we’d like to encourage all website owners to switch from HTTP to HTTPS to keep everyone safe on the web.

#### It’s duplicate content

If the HTTP and HTTPS versions of the page are appearing as distinct results in the Google index, they are duplicate content. At best, your SEO "juice" will be split between the pages.

Comment: Using HSTS along with canonical URLs is a much neater way of handling this.

Answer (score 1):

Always use one URL for one piece of content. Like @Tim above said you should 301 redirect, or [use Canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because your server is serving up both http and https versions. I would advise you to serve only HTTPS requests (there are ways to handle this at the server level)

Regarding SEO, it's not a good practice and you don't want to be penalized for duplicate content.